# Retrieving parameters from a script or command in hosted powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, clr

I'm hosting PowerShell inside my VB.net application. I want to be able to figure out at run time what parameters any random script that I'm running takes. For example, given the code:

```
 Using powerShellObject As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create

    powerShellObject.AddScript("get-process")
    powerShellObject.AddParameter("FileVersionInfo", "")
    Dim output As New PSDataCollection(Of PSObject)()
    AddHandler output.DataAdded, AddressOf Output_DataAdded
    AddHandler powerShellObject.InvocationStateChanged, AddressOf Powershell_InvocationStateChanged

    ' Invoke the pipeline asynchronously.
    Dim asyncResult As IAsyncResult = powerShellObject.BeginInvoke(Of PSObject, PSObject)(Nothing, output)

    While powerShellObject.InvocationStateInfo.State <> PSInvocationState.Completed
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0)
    End While

End Using
```

I want to be able to determine what parameters the script I add via 'AddScript' takes (I know that get-process can take

```
Get-Process [-ComputerName <String[]>] [-FileVersionInfo] [-Module] -Id <Int32[]> [<CommonParameters>]
```

but I want my users to be able to submit any random script and I want to be able to figure out what those parameters are at runtime.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-Command -Syntax MyScript.ps1
```

will return the syntax. I assume this is limited to processing a `param` statement from the script (doing anything more would be rather hard).

This works for cmdlets as well (and is very useful as a, quicker than reading the help, lookup of parameter names).

To get per parameter data:

```
(Get-Command MyScript).Parameters
```

is a hash keyed by parameter name of [`System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.parametermetadata%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which contains all sorts of interesting information.

Comment: thank you Richard, that works nicely.  I hadnt thought of invoking a different powershell cmd to get the information, I was wearing blinkers and expecting a managed way of doing it.